# How do I get a value node moved up to be an attribute of its parent node?

Tags: python, soap, suds

What do I need to change so the Name node under FieldRef is an attribute of FieldRef, and not a child node?

Suds currently generates the following soap:

```
<ns0:query>
  <ns0:Where>
    <ns0:Eq>
      <ns0:FieldRef>
        <ns0:Name>_ows_ID</ns0:Name>
      </ns0:FieldRef>
      <ns0:Value>66</ns0:Value>
    </ns0:Eq>
  </ns0:Where>
</ns0:query>
```

What I need is this:

```
<ns0:query>
  <ns0:Where>
     <ns0:Eq>
        <ns0:FieldRef Name="_ows_ID">
        </ns0:FieldRef>
        <ns0:Value>66</ns0:Value>
     </ns0:Eq>
  </ns0:Where>
</ns0:query>
```

The first xml structure is generated by suds from the below code.

```
q = c.factory.create('GetListItems.query')
q['Where']=InstFactory.object('Where')
q['Where']['Eq']=InstFactory.object('Eq')
q['Where']['Eq']['FieldRef']=InstFactory.object('FieldRef')
q['Where']['Eq']['FieldRef'].Name='_ows_ID'
q['Where']['Eq']['Value']='66'
```

and `print(q)` results in

```
(query){
   Where = 
      (Where){
         Eq = 
            (Eq){
               FieldRef = 
                  (FieldRef){
                     Name = "_ows_ID"
                  }
               Value = "66"
            }
      }
 }
```

Here's the code that makes the WS call that creates the soap request

```
c = client.Client(url='https://community.site.edu/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL',
                  transport=WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='domain\user',
                                                     password='password')
                                             )
ll= c.service.GetListItems(listName="{BD59F6D9-AB4B-474D-BCC7-E4B4BEA7EB27}",
                             viewName="{407A6AB9-97CF-4E1F-8544-7DD67CEA997B}",
                             query=q
                             )
```

Comment: so what exactly is the question? You can't get the first to look like the second?

Comment: @Jack What do I need to change so the Name node under FieldRef is an attribute of FieldRef, and not a child node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from suds.sax.element import Element
#create the nodes
q = Element('query')
where=Element('Where')
eq=Element('Eq')
fieldref=Element('FieldRef')
fieldref.set('Name', '_ows_ID')
value=Element('Value')
value.setText('66')

#append them
eq.append(fieldref)
eq.append(value)
where.append(eq)
q.append(where)
```

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/TipsAndTricks

> Including Literal XML
>
> To include literal (not escaped) XML
>   as a parameter value of object
>   attribute, you need to set the value
>   of the parameter of the object
>   attribute to be a sax Element. The
>   marshaller is designed to simply
>   attach and append content that is
>   already XML.
>
> For example, you want to pass the
>   following XML as a parameter:
>
> `<query>   <name>Elmer Fudd</name>`
>   `<age unit="years">33</age>`
>   `<job>Wabbit Hunter</job> </query>`
>
> The can be done as follows:
>
> ```
> from suds.sax.element import Element
> query = Element('query')
> name = Element('name').setText('Elmer Fudd')
> age = Element('age').setText('33')
> age.set('units', 'years')
> job = Element('job').setText('Wabbit Hunter')
> query.append(name)
> query.append(age)
> query.append(job)
> client.service.runQuery(query)
> ```